# SSRS Filter on 2nd list

Tags: join, reporting-services, filter

I have two SharePoint lists that have “RequestID” in common.  The primary list for the report is “Action Items”, but I only want to see those records where the Application equals the selected parameter.  The Application is in the “Requests” list.

[image: Table structures]

I want to filter for the `Application name = 'Math'`, so in this case, I would only get Action Item Ids 44 and 55 which relate to Requests #15 and #22.
I have successfully displayed the name of the application in the report using this:

```
=Join(LookupSet(CInt(Fields!Request_ID.Value), CInt(Fields!ID.Value), Fields!Application.Value, "Requests"), ", ")
```

But, I understand that you cannot use a Lookup in a filter.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be using **Cascading Parameters** to do what you want.

With Cascading Parameters, you select the **Application** in one parameter and then base the selection for the **Action Items** parameter that uses the Application parameter.

With SQL you could filter the dataset for the **ActionItemID**s:

```
SELECT ActionItemID 
FROM ACTION_ITEMS 
WHERE REQUEST_ID IN (SELECT REQUEST_ID FROM REQUESTS WHERE APPLICATION = @APPLICATION_PARAMETER )
```

But you can FILTER the Action Item SharePoint list on the DataSets **FILTER** tab:

**Expression**:

```
=IIF(INSTR(
    Join(LookupSet(Parameters!@APPLICATION_PARAMETER.Value, Fields!Application.Value, Fields!ID.Value, "Requests"), ",") & ","
    , Fields!Request_ID.Value & ",") > 0, 1, 0)
```

This looks for the **Request ID** being in the list (from the LookUp [15,22,]) of ID with the Parameter (MATH) as the App.

[image]

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337169(v=sql.100).aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337498(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: There is only one parameter in the report, "Application".  Remember this is using SharePoint Lists - no SQL.  I could easily do it with SQL.  This list of values for the parameter come from another SP list "Applications".  The parameter correctly displays the applications.  The problem is trying to get the Application from the Requests list when I am querying the Action Items list.

Comment: I thought SharePoint might be the problem - I haven't worked with it as a source. You can't use it as a **DataSource**? https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2068/using-a-sharepoint-list-as-a-data-source-in-sql-server-reporting-services-2008-r2/

Comment: Yes, you can use a SharePoint list as a datasource, But you can not join it to another SharePoint list... that is the whole problem.

Comment: You can't join the datasets, but you can filter one dataset based on the selected parameter based on another dataset. Pick the first parameter from the **REQUESTS** list and add a **FILTER** based on the parameter on the **Action Items** list. I added a new pic.

Comment: This does not work.  This is like saying RequestID 1234 = Math...  I tried it just for grins, but I get back no data.

Comment: You're right - I'm not sure how I was thinking it would work. You would need to get the **RequestID** values from the Requests database using a JOIN LookUpSet similar to what you had originally. I have added an update to my answer.

Comment: Perhaps you have not seen this message before:  A FilterExpression for the dataset 'ActionItems' includes a Lookup function.  Lookup functions cannot be used in expressions in a dataset filter.   You can't have a lookup in a filter - I had said that originally...

Comment: I have seen it before but wasn't thinking about it when trying to figure out a work around for using a **SharePoint** list. My other thought was to create an extra **Requests** dataset and hidden parameter to hold the **Request_ID**s from the second Requests dataset (filtered by the @APPLICATION parameter from the first **Requests** dataset/parameter). The first parameter would return `MATH`, the second (hidden) would then return `15,22`. The **Action_Item** dataset would then filter on the `15,22`. A bit overly complicated though for something that shouldn't need to be.